# How to get Tuple property by property index in c#?

Tags: c#, tuples

I need to implement `Comparison` delegate for Tuple. And I have a column number by which I want to compare Tuples.

For now I got to:

```
int sortedColumn;
Comparison<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> tupleComparison = (x, y) =>
{
    // I want to access x.Item2 if sortedColumn = 2
        // x.Item3 if sortedColumn = 2 etc      
};
```

How can I do this in c#?

Can I do it without using `switch`?

Comment: you can do it, x.Item2 should work, what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to write N number of if/switch checks

Comment: T1,T2,T3 are of same type?

Comment: no, they are of different types, they would be if I'd written: Tuple<T,T,T> :)

Comment: Any relation between T1,T2,T3? post what you compare inside so that we get more idea of how it can be simplified

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi, I think 3 switch cases is better than reflection...

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, mabby when I know that I have 3 cases. If I don't know at compile time this number, reflection is necessary

Comment: but if it is a tuple, count is always limited right? or it may be something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with `if`/`else` or `switch`, but if you want to avoid that (e.g. so you can use it with any `Tuple`), you can use reflection:

```
Comparison<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> tupleComparison = (x, y) =>
{
    var prop = typeof(Tuple<T1, T2, T3>).GetProperty("Item" + sortedColumn);
    var xItem = prop.GetValue(x);
    var yItem = prop.GetValue(y);
    return // something to compare xItem and yItem
};
```

Comment: awesome! just what I always needed:)

Answer (score 3):

A perhaps unknown fact is that all tuples implement the somewhat obscure interface `ITuple`. The interface defines two methods (`Length` returning the number of items in the tuple, and an index access method, `[]` - which is zero-based), but both of them are hidden, meaning that you have to explicitly cast your tuple variable to the implemented interface, and then use the relevant method.

Note that you have to cast the accessed item finally to its innate type, as the index access method always returns an `object`.

```
Comparison<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> tupleComparison = (x, y) =>
{
    var columnValue = (int)((ITuple)x)[sortedColumn];     // Don't forget to cast to relevant type
};
```